# exchange online - The I / O operation was aborted

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I running a simple code:Set-MailboxCalendarConfiguration on about 700 users but I keep getting The I / O operation was aborted error.

I thought it was a session issue so I added to code $EOLSession.state -eq 'Broken' -or !$EOLSession

That did not work.
So I googled more and i found that it might be related to WinRM service so I added more code.
That also did not work ...I can't find anything else.
Can someone help me please?

my code is below:

```
foreach ($user in $users) {
try
{
Function Reconnect-ExchangeOnline 
    {
if ($EOLSession.state -eq 'Broken' -or !$EOLSession) 
    {
    Disconnect-ExchangeOnline; Start-Sleep -Seconds 3; Connect-ExchangeOnline
    }    
}
$serviceWinRM = get-service WinRM
if ( $serviceWinRM.Status -eq "Stopped")
{ 
start-service WinRM;Start-Sleep -Seconds 4
}
    Set-MailboxCalendarConfiguration -identity $user.userprincipalname -WorkDays Weekdays  -WeekStartDay "Monday"
}
catch 
    {
    $Error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName
    Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName xxxxxx
    }}
```

Comment: Tel us what is in `$user` and `$users`.. Inside the lop your code uses `$user.users` which seems quite odd...

Comment: its a simple csv containing userprincipalnames in a column named "users".
Users
-------------
a.b@contoso.com
b.a@contoso.com

etc. So the variable is named users and column name is named users so....I get its a bit confusing :).

Comment: Aha, so my first thought would be to stop the confusion and rename the columnheader into `UserPrincipalName` to make it clear what you are trying to do..

Comment: Yea I did not expect such issues with such a simple thing....my bad...